# How to pass bytes type parameters to a function in java web3

Tags: java, proxy, web3-java

I am trying to deploy a proxy contract and it has the following constructor

`constructor(address beacon, bytes memory data,string memory assetId)`
These are the inputs I am trying to pass to this constructor

1. beacon - 0xa7cF300E62EA5c7eA611e71Fb30A41182AC3ACDD
2. data - 0x000000000000000000000000a7cf300e
3. assetId -"1"

The following is the code I have written

```
                    FunctionEncoder.encodeConstructor(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    new Address(beaconAddress),
                                    new DynamicBytes("0x000000000000000000000000a7cf300e".getBytes()),
                                    new Utf8String("1")));
```

The ideal output should be something like this

```
000000000000000000000000a7cf300e62ea5c7ea611e71fb30a41182ac3acdd000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000a7cf300e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But what I recieve is something like this

```
000000000000000000000000a7cf300e62ea5c7ea611e71fb30a41182ac3acdd000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000223078303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030613763663330306500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

What I think has happened is that the `data` field in the constructor  has been converted to a string of bytes. So what I am looking for is a solution/method to pass `bytes` type parameters to a function. There is a way to do this win web3.js. I a wondering anyone knows a way to do this in web3-java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly passing the bytes to the `encodeConstructor` function use the following method

`byte[] myBytes = parseHexBinary("0x000000000000000000000000a7cf300e");`

`parseHexBinary` is taken from the  `DatatypeConverter` class.

Then pass this byte array to the `encodeConstructor` as below

```
String encodedConstructor =
                    FunctionEncoder.encodeConstructor(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    new Address(beaconAddress),
                                    new DynamicBytes(myBytes),
                                    new Utf8String("1")));
```